# Closing a Activity on new Activity

Tags: android

I have an activity that has a button with a intent as follows

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyMainActivity.class);
                   startActivity(i);
                   finish();
```

Once you move to the next activity `MyMainActivity.class` if you hit the back button it shows the last activity with the old resaults.

Is there a way to make the activity close or move back once the button is pushed? This way once the activity is done it is not my activity history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this along with intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyMainActivity.class);
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                   startActivity(i);
                   finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyMainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

best practice is to @override the `onPause()` in the activity.
`onPause()` method is called whenever the control moves to new activity.

so call the `finish()` method in the `onPause()`.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
        finish();
}
```