# Activity should called only once

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing an application and in that case I've some activities which I don't want to show them again e.g like i have a splash screen which is my activity and i don't want it to show again on back key press.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **android:noHistory="true"** to the activity entry at the AndroidManifest.xml. That will prevent the activity from being saved on the stack.

Comment: Just an FYI: `getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);`

Answer (score 1):

Call `finish()` on the activity after you call `startActivity()` to start the next one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a manifest parameter that lets you permanently disable activity stack history for particular activities.

See: [Removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

Answer (score 0):

[Closing a Activity on new Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775341/closing-a-activity-on-new-activity/5775373#5775373)